# How to install and use scatter3d without pause in R 3.3.2?

Tags: debian, software-installation, r

I am trying to get interactive 3D scatter in R 3.3.2 by following the instructions [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/amazing-interactive-3d-scatter-plots-r-software-and-data-visualization) and studying Rtsne 3d capabilities [here](https://github.com/jkrijthe/Rtsne/issues/12#issuecomment-269751844). 
I try to use dynamic colors by `RColorBrewer` with any 3D color plotting package, here chosen `scatter3d`. 
I did not find any package called `scatter3d` so I am not sure where the function precisely is. 
I get the following notice as root by `install.packages('scatter3d')`. I did already `install.packages('rgl')`

```
package ‘scatter3d’ is not available (for R version 3.3.2)
```

### Pseudocode example [not necessary for the case]

I show the following code because I am not sure how you can get `scatter3d` in Linux

```
## Startup
# Mx <- [choose any matrix here]
N <- length(Mx)
perplex <- 0

library('Rtsne')
# https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/788739/Visualization-of-High-Dimensional-Data-using-t-SNE

# https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rtsne/Rtsne.pdf
rtsne_out <- Rtsne(as.matrix(Mx), perplexity = perplex, 
  dims=3,
  pca=TRUE, 
  check_duplicates=FALSE
)

## Fails because missing package scatter3d 
library('RColorBrewer')
library('rgl') # scatter3d
colors <- brewer.pal(n=N, name="Dark2")
# TODO scatter3d not available in R 3.3.2
scatter3d(x=rtsne_out$Y[,1],y=rtsne_out$Y[,2],z=rtsne_out$Y[,3], 
          surface=FALSE, grid = FALSE, ellipsoid = TRUE,
          surface.col = colors)
```

### Testing Rodrigo's answer

Rodrigo's successful points: Do `install.packages('car')` which is a regression package, not a data package.

I call the following function inside a function. After finishing the function, the interactive `scatter3d` closes, which is problematic because then I cannot use visualise the interactive window anymore, since the running time is short

```
scatter3d(x=rtsne_out$Y[,1],y=rtsne_out$Y[,2],z=rtsne_out$Y[,3], 
          surface=FALSE, grid = FALSE, ellipsoid = TRUE,
          surface.col = colors)
```

I try to return the visualisation object inside the function unsuccessfully by

```
result <- scatter3d(...)
return(result)
```

Having keystroke pause does not help in the function, and neither outside the function; the run of the script just goes on and the visualisation ends without leaving the window open

```
result
cat ("Press [enter] to continue") # http://stackoverflow.com/a/18746519/54964
line <- readline()
#readline(prompt="Press [enter] to continue") # http://stackoverflow.com/a/18746519/54964
```

Doing `par(ask=TRUE) #http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Pause-on-graphics-td845261.html` before `scatter3d` does not help neither.

OS: Debian 8.5
R: 3.3.2

Comment: library(rgl) already lets you interactively rotate a 3d scatter plot. Maybe that's enough for your needs?

Comment: Added the example as an answer. There's a scatter3d function in car package. Aren't you confusing it with a non-existent scatter3d library?

Answer (score 1):

A simple example, using `rgl` library.

```
install.packages('rgl',depend=T)
library(rgl)
ce <- read.csv('_CE3D.txt',sep='\t',header=T)
cd <- read.csv('_CD3D.txt',sep='\t',header=T)
plot3d(ce$x,ce$y,ce$z)
plot3d(cd$x,cd$y,cd$z,add=T,col=2)
```

The images are from a different example, but only to illustrate. You may click and drag the mouse to rotate.

[image: plot1]
[image: plot2]

Comment: What is this `depend=T`? Your proposal seems to work. I am using `scatter3d`. The window closes after the script finishes. I am thinking how to prevent this. I want to work with the interactive window. - - Please, add `library('car')` also in your answer because I seriously thought that it is just a data package but it is not. Your answer and your last comment are really helpful!

Comment: depend=T (short for dependencies=TRUE) install all other necessary packages. I could add library(car), but I haven't used it to produce the above graphics. Glad to help.